# How to find pairs with product greater than sum

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Supposing that we have a array C with all element in C > 0

A pair of indices `(a, b)` is multiplicative if `0 ≤ a < b < N` and `C[a] * C[b] ≥ C[a] + C[b]`.
with the time-complexity is O ( n )

- expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);

I appreciate your help in supporting this case.
Thanks.

Comment: If the output is all such pairs, wouldn't that be `O(N^2)` in the worst case?  Or do we just need to know the number of such pairs?  Or (assuming `C` is sorted) the minimal `b` for each `a`?

Answer (score 11):

The O(N) solution is here.

It is supposed that elements in the array are sorted in non-decreasing order.
If the array is not sorted, then worst-time complexity O(N) is unreacheble.

The original condition `C[a] * C[b] ≥ C[a] + C[b]` can easily be expressed as `C[b] ≥ C[a] / (C[a] - 1)`

So, Looking at the graph of `C[a] / (C[a] - 1)` ...

[image]

...we can see that:

1. If `0 ≤ C[a] < 1`, then `(a, b)` is multiplicative only if `C[a] = 0`
2. If `1 < C[a] < 2`, then `C[a] / (C[a] - 1) > 2`, therefore `C[b] > 2`. So, `C[b] > C[a]`, but this is impossible because `C[a] ≥ C[b]` (because the array is sorted).
3. If `C[a] > 2` then the pair is multiplicative for any `C[b]` where `C[b] ≥ C[a] / (C[a] - 1)`

So, the code in C# may look like:

```
int count_pairs(double[] C)
{
  int result = 0;
  int len = C.Length;

  if (len > 1)
  {
    int lo_index;
    int hi_index = len - 1;

    // Skip all C[i] less than 1
    for (lo_index = 0; lo_index < len; lo_index++)
    {
      if (C[lo_index] > 1)
        break;
    }

    while (hi_index > lo_index)
    {
      double v = C[hi_index] / (C[hi_index] - 1);

      while (lo_index < hi_index && C[lo_index] < v)
      {
        lo_index++;
      }

      if (lo_index == hi_index)
        break;

      result += (hi_index - lo_index);

      hi_index--;

    }
  }
  return result;  
}
```

Comment: But, Do we need sort c array before ?

Comment: Sure, the array should be sorted first. It is impossible to achieve O(N) without such precondition.

Comment: the input {2} should return 1 (the pair (2,2)). the input {2,3} should return 4 (the pairs (2,2)(2,3)(3,2)(3,3)). This is definitely on the right path, but seems to need debugging.

Comment: I think {2} is not valid input, as we have the restriction: 0 ≤ a < b < N. So the input array should contain at least two elements. The same is for the second case: we have the strong inequality "a < b" so, we can't pair an array member with itself.

Comment: As the question stands atm, the input {2} is very much valid, and the output should be 0 - there are no such pairs of (a,b). In this sense the solution is correct. There are 3 points to make however. 1. the OP has for some reason omitted that the array is sorted as a precondition - that was present in the first version. 2. The OP has also excluded 0s from C for some reason. (Again, not really a fault with this answer, but really, changing the prereqs when there are already answers present is bullshit). 3. This solution seems to break for {1.1, 1.2} with ArrayOutOfBounds in the inner while

Comment: Oh and lastly: Code only answers are generally not very good quality. Would you care to explain how this works (What does `double v = C[hi_index] / (C[hi_index] - 1);` mean?) and why it gives the correct answer? For a really good answer you'd also want to give an explanation or hint as to how to arrive at such a solution.

Comment: I disagree regarding correctness of input {2} because we have a precondition `a < b`, therefore `C[a]` and `C[b]` can not be the same element of the array. So the array must consists of at least two elements.
Ordous, thank you for the notice! Indeed the algorithm crashed with input `{1.1, 1.2}`. I fixed the inner loop to avoid this.

Comment: This is great solution, but the only problem that it has it's a case when you have more then 1 leading zeros.

Comment: I got this result from Codility.com "for the input ([0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0]) the solution returned a wrong answer (got 1 expected 2)."

Answer (score 2):

As always with competition problems, you have to solve the problem before you code it. In this case you'll need some basic algebra. I'll ignore the strange formatting of numbers and operate only on `C`.

So, given a non-negative number `a`, what non-negative number `b` would yield `a * b >= a + b`?
`a * b >= a + b` => `b * (a-1) >= a`
Now, we have 4 cases:

1. 0 < a < 1. In this case the next step is `b <= a / (a-1)`. Note that the RHS is negative, while `b` is non-negative. Hence **there are no such `b`**
2. a == 0. Next step is `-b >= 0`, hence, since b is non-negative, **b == 0**
3. a == 1. Next step is `b * 0 >= 1` which simplifies to *false*. Hence, **there are no such `b`**
4. 1 < a. Next step is `b >= a / (a-1)`. This is the only non-trivial case.

This, in itself, already gives you an O(N* log(N)) algorithm:
Iterate through the array keeping the sum. For each number, if it is 0, find the number of 0s in the array and add them to the sum. If it is 0 < `num` <= 1, add 0. If it is > 1, add the number of values >= `num / (num-1)`. **Since the array is ascending you can use binary search to find those values in `log(N)` time**, giving you a total `N * log(N)` worstcase runtime (And `O(N)` best runtime, in case all values are the noops - between 0 and 1)

To make the last step to optimize the algorithm even further to O(N) you need to observe how the function `x / (x-1)` behaves when x > 1 and x is growing (i.e. what will your search target be as you iterate through the array).

Comment: I don't see a O(n) solution in there.

Comment: @Andreas Well... Too bad? I do.

Comment: @user3737020 The solution I presented is O(N log(N)), along with a pretty strong hint as to how to achieve O(N). Do you really need a full solution down to the code?

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same challenge. It looks like you forgot the case of multiple inputs of 0, since 0*0 = 0+0;

```
class Solution {
    public static final long ONE_MILLION = 1000000;
    public static final int LIMIT = 1000000000;

    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
        // need to redo algebra term is such that B >= A/A-1
        //so if A < 1 only possible if C[a] =0 and C[b] = 0
        //if A < 2 is impossible since sorted
        //if A > possible

        if (A.length < 2) { return 0;}
        int numberOfMP = 0;
        int lowIndex = 0;
        int highIndex = A.length-1;

        if (A[0] == 0 && B [0] == 0) {
            int index = 1;
            int increaseAmount = 1;
            while (A[index] == 0 && B[index] == 0) {
                numberOfMP += increaseAmount;
                increaseAmount++;
            }

        }

        while(lowIndex < highIndex){
            //don't convert to double to avoid precision errors
            long C_low = convertValue(A[lowIndex], B[lowIndex]);
            long C_high;
            //avoid useless calculations for values we already know will fail
            if(C_low >= ONE_MILLION) {
                C_low = convertValue(A[lowIndex], B[lowIndex]);
                C_high = convertValue(A[highIndex], B[highIndex]);
                //note that since both inputs to the product were scaled, we need to scale the sum twice
                //not a scaleable solution...
                if( C_low * C_high >= (C_low + C_high) * ONE_MILLION) {
                    numberOfMP += highIndex - lowIndex;
                    highIndex--;
                }else{
                    lowIndex++;
                }
            }else{
                lowIndex++;
            }
        }

        if (numberOfMP > LIMIT) {
            return LIMIT;
        }
        return numberOfMP;
    }

    private long convertValue(int a, int b) {
        return (long) a * ONE_MILLION + (long) b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my tested C# version of O(N) solution.

Note: my exercise was a bit more complex.

The incoming parameters contains `N` `(0..100,000)` non-negative numbers where `A` array contains the integral part of the number `(0..1,000)` and `B` array contains the fractional part of the number `(0..999,999)`.

The numbers represented by `A` and `B` arrays are sorted in non-decreasing order.

If the number of pairs is greater than `1,000,000,000` then the function should return `1,000,000,000`.

```cs
class Solution
{
    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B)
    {
        // a == 0    => b == 0
        // 0 < a < 1 => no b
        // a == 1    => no b
        // 1 < a     => b >= a / (a - 1)

        if (A.Length < 2)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int result = 0;
        int currentIndex = 0;
        int maxIndex = A.Length - 1;

        const int OneMillion = 1000000;
        const int OneBillion = 1000000000;

        // Counting zeros
        while (currentIndex < A.Length && A[currentIndex] == 0 && B[currentIndex] == 0)
        {
            currentIndex++;
        }

        // Adding number of pairs of zeros
        if (currentIndex > 1)
        {
            // n = currentIndex - 1
            // sum(1..n) => (n + 1) * (int)(n / 2) + (n % 2) * (int)((n + 1) / 2)

            decimal n = new Decimal(currentIndex - 1);
            decimal numberOfPairsOfZeros = (n + 1) * (int)(n / 2) + (n % 2) * (int)((n + 1) / 2);

            result += (numberOfPairsOfZeros > OneBillion ? OneBillion : (int)numberOfPairsOfZeros);

            if (result >= OneBillion)
            {
                return OneBillion;
            }
        }

        if (currentIndex == A.Length)
        {
            return result;
        }

        // Skip values where 0 < A.B <= 1.001000
        // 1.001000 can be in pair with numbers >= 1001.000000 but the maximum number is 1000.999999;
        // 1.001001 can be in pair with numbers >= 1000.000999;
        while
        (
            currentIndex < A.Length
            &&
            (
                A[currentIndex] == 0
                ||
                (
                    A[currentIndex] == 1
                    && B[currentIndex] < 1001
                )
            )
        )
        {
            currentIndex++;
        }

        if (currentIndex == A.Length)
        {
            return result;
        }

        // From this point 1 < A.B, so we look for A2.B2 values where A2.B2 >= A.B / (A.B - 1)
        for (int i = currentIndex; i < A.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            // number between 1.001001 and 2 should be searched only
            if (A[i] == 1)
            {
                // Search numbers greater than or equals to A.B / (A.B - 1)
                // A.B / (A.B - 1) = 1.B / (1.B - 1) = 1.B / 0.B = 1 / 0.B + 1
                double scaledOnePerBFractionalPart = (double)OneMillion / (double)B[i] * (double)OneMillion;
                int scaledMinValue = (int)scaledOnePerBFractionalPart + OneMillion + (Math.Ceiling(scaledOnePerBFractionalPart) == scaledOnePerBFractionalPart ? 0 : 1);

                while (maxIndex > i && OneMillion * A[maxIndex] + B[maxIndex] >= scaledMinValue)
                {
                    maxIndex--;
                }

                result += A.Length - 1 - maxIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                // In this case the number is greater than or equal to 2.
                // So we just add the remaining indexes as number of pairs.
                result += A.Length - 1 - i;
            }

            if (result >= OneBillion)
            {
                return OneBillion;
            }
        }

        return result >= OneBillion ? OneBillion : result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow @Gabor, you scored 100 at Codility test. Good job :)

Answer (score 0):

The following condition:

> A pair of indices (P, Q) is multiplicative if 0 ≤ P < Q < N and C[P] * C[Q] ≥ C[P] + C[Q].

Combined with the presorted arrays:

> 4. real numbers created from arrays are sorted in non-decreasing order.

Allows a O(n) solution. Perhaps if you debug through your solution you'll see a pattern.

Comment: The OP already stated that he wants a O(N) solution, and the conditions you quoted are, in fact, *all* of the conditions that don't have to do with formatting. As such, I cannot see any value in this answer.

Comment: +Andreas : Please tell me more details about your answers :)

Comment: I wish I could, but this looks like homework. Here is a hint: try traversing the data once, but keeping two positions, A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Java solution for the sample challenge, slightly better readable:

```
private static final double ONE_MILLION = 1000000.0d;
private static final int THRESHOLD = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
private static final double ERROR = 0.5d / ONE_MILLION / ONE_MILLION;

public int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
    return solution(IntStream
            .range(0, Math.min(A.length, B.length)).parallel()
            .mapToDouble(i -> A[i] + B[i] / ONE_MILLION).toArray());
}

public int solution(double[] C) {
    int n = C.length;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (C[i] < 1) {
            int indexOfLastZero = -Arrays.binarySearch(C, i + 1, n, ERROR) - 1;
            result += indexOfLastZero - (i + 1);
        } else {
            double c = C[i] / (double) (C[i] - 1) - ERROR;
            int indexOfFirstGreater = -Arrays.binarySearch(C, i + 1, n, c) - 1;
            result += n - indexOfFirstGreater;
        }
        if (result > THRESHOLD) {
            return THRESHOLD;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is supposed that elements in the array are sorted in non-decreasing order.
My O(N) solution in JavaScript:

```
function solution(A, B) {
    var scale = 1000000;
    var N = A.length;
    var count=0;
    var left = 0;
    var right = N-1;
    var C_left = 0;

    while(left<right){
    //to avoid rounding errors, use multiplication
        C_left = A[left]*scale+B[left];
        if(C_left>=scale){

            if(C_left*(A[right]*scale+B[right])>=(C_left+(A[right]*scale+B[right]))*scale){
                // if C[left],C[right] is ok, that means that all elements C[left++],C[right] to satisfy condition
                count+=right-left;
                right--;
            }else{
                left++;
            }
        }else{
            left++;
        }
    }
    //condition from codility.com test
    if(count>1000000000)
        return 1000000000;
    else{
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not copying here my algorithm, but my idea seems to be O(n) also.

1, calculate the minimum possible complete graph first.
divide the sorted array to 2 (at the mid index) - round up (so it's a left leaning tree)

and check the first element with the last one, increase the first index until you don't get a pass - calculate the edges of complete graph - n * (n-1) / 2

if we don't get a pass it's O(N) worst case. And we are not storing anything N dependently, just 2-3 temporary int to calculate the diff (CP*CQ) - (CP+CQ) should be >= 0

2, remove all the edges which has not get a pass

so where we have got a pass in the 1) continue the check, but with the next element, not the last one, until we have got a pass. each iteration decreasing the first result - as removing from complete graph, and return the result.

The 2) just continuing the algorithm, which means O(N) worst case has been distributed between 1) and 2)

Unfortunately i just tested myself, but would not have passed on this test, as it took me 3 hours at least.:(