# CountMultiplicativePairs in Python using optimized way

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The complete problem is given below for which I wrote a Python code and wanted to know the complexity of it or whether it can be optimised more. The solutions are available in C# but the logics are quiet complex.

http://www.whatsjs.com/2018/01/codility-countmultiplicativepairs.html

Here is the solution to the problem:
[How to find pairs with product greater than sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750240/how-to-find-pairs-with-product-greater-than-sum)

Below the code I wrote in Python. Is there any other way or someone who has tried this problem in python as  the C# code explained above doesn't have proper explanation

```
def solution(A,B):
    """
    Count the number of pairs (x, y) such that x * y >= x + y. 
    """
    M = 1000*1000
    max_count=1000*1000*1000
    zero=count=0
    if len(A)<=1:
        return "Length of array A should be greater than 1"
    if len(B)<=1:
        return "Length of array B should be greater than 1"
    if len(A)!=len(B):
        return "Length of both arrays should be equal"
    C=[0]*len(A)
    for (i, elem) in enumerate(A):
        C[i]=float(A[i])+float(B[i]/M)
    for (i, elem) in enumerate(C):
        if elem==0:
            zero+=1
            
        if elem>0 and elem<=1:
           
            pass
        if elem>1:
            
            
            for j in range(i+1,len(C)):
                
                if round(C[i]*C[j],2)>=C[i]+C[j]:
                    count+=1
    zero_pairs=int(zero*(zero-1)/2)
    count+=zero_pairs
    return min(count,max_count)
    
    
    
    #return C
                    

#print(solution([0,1,2,2,3,5], [500000, 500000, 0, 0, 0, 20000]))
print(solution([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6],[200000, 250000, 500000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))

# print(solution([0, 0, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0]))
# print(solution([1, 3], [500000, 10000]))
# print(solution([1, 3], [400000, 500000]))
#print(solution([0, 0, 0, 0] , [0, 0, 0, 0]))
#print(solution([0, 0, 0, 0] , [1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

I wanted a more optimised way to solve this, as I feel the complexity currently is O(n^2)

Comment: What exactly do you find "complex" in the given C# solution? Have you tried translating it to Python?

Answer (score 0):

if non negative pair (x,y)

x*y < x + y

=> x < y/(y-1)

the expression y/(y-1) gets smaller for higher y values

assuming the list is sorted

start from the last place,

compare the expression y/(y-1) to the list

all the values bigger then it are it's pairs

inserting to a sorted list ~ O(Log(n))

for N values gives complexity of nlog(n)